# Can the order of inverse limit and direct sum be changed for the symmetric polynomial rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading the book *Symmetric Functions and Orthogonal Polynomials* by I.G. Macdonald. On page 1 of chapter 1, the book defines *the ring of symmetric functions* as
$$\Lambda=\oplus_{r\ge0}\lim_{\overleftarrow{n}}\Lambda_n^r,$$
where $\Lambda_n^r$ denotes the additive group of homogeneous symmetric polynomials of degree $r$ in $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, and the $\displaystyle\lim_{\leftarrow}$ denotes the inverse limit.

I don't quite sure if the order of direct sum and inverse limit really matters here. And I guess it does no effect with the order changing. However, I have no idea how to prove or disprove.

All in all, my question is whether the equality
$$\oplus_{r\ge0}\lim_{\overleftarrow{n}}\Lambda_n^r=\lim_{\overleftarrow{n}}\oplus_{r\ge0}\Lambda_n^r$$
holds with the notation declared above. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* actually matter. In the RHS ring, the degree can increase with $n$, for instance there is an element that deserves to be called $\sum_n x_n^n$, whereas the same cannot be said on the LHS.

An element of the LHS has a maximum degree, and all the monomials appearing in the series representing the element have to have degree bounded by that single degree, which is not the case on the RHS, where the only requirement is that if you fix $n$, then the monomials involving variables $x_i, i\leq n$ have a maximal degree.

Making that argument precise shows that the canonical map LHS $\to$ RHS is not surjective

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you a lot!